# how to convert date to millisecond at Java?

Tags: java, datetime

```
long beginupd = new GregorianCalendar(2014,3,14,10,55,25).getTime().getTime();              
Date date = new Date();
long milli=date.getTime();           

System.out.println(beginupd);
System.out.println(milli);
System.out.println(date);
```

output:

1397462125000

1394787327009

Fri Mar 14 10:55:27 EET 2014

What is my wrong? why is it not equal? difference onyl two second but output difference very large

OK!
0 for January and 11 for December. thank you David Wallace

Comment: What format is the input in?  Is it a `String`?  Is it `Date` value?

Comment: YES!  If you have a `String` value, you need parse it back to a `Date` so you can get the milliseconds.  If you already have a `Date` value, then you don't need to do the parsing...I also assume you're trying to get the duration between these two values...Which can be seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119665/geting-duration-of-2-times/18120233#18120233) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851934/how-to-find-difference-between-two-joda-time-datetimes-in-minutes/12852021#12852021)

Comment: @user2772836 Parse it into a `Date` then use [`Date.getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()). The date format is arbitrary as long as you can construct an appropriate [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to represent it.

Comment: Parse it to a date using `SimpleDateFormat` and call the `getTime()` method. That should probably do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert UTC date into milliseconds JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081417/convert-utc-date-into-milliseconds-java)

Comment: MadProgrammer if I say that I want to calculate 3+5, will you say that it is int or double?   it is doesn't matter.

Comment: @user2772836 Please keep comment discussions directly related to the problem at hand.

Comment: What on earth does `2014-14-03` mean?  Did the year just get longer?

Comment: @DavidWallace yyyy-dd-MM I presume. A little odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because the deprecated `Date` constructor that you're using expects `year - 1900` as the first argument.

You should either use a `SimpleDateFormat` or a `GregorianCalendar` to do this conversion instead.  Since there is already an excellent answer here, showing the use of `SimpleDateFormat`, here's how you use `GregorianCalendar` for 1:39am on 14 March 2014.

```
new GregorianCalendar(2014, 2, 14, 1, 39, 0).getTime().getTime();
```

Beware that the month uses 0 for January and 11 for December.

Comment: 1397430420000
1394755672098 yes, this is only 1 second diffrence but this diffrence very big

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying.  What are those two numbers?

Comment: That difference looks like approximately 31 days to me.  Did you enter 2 for March, instead of 3, like I suggested?  (The deprecated Date constructor also needs 2 for March).

Answer (score 2):

If it is not already a `Date`, parse it into a `Date`. The date format is arbitrary as long as you can construct an appropriate [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to represent it.

After you have a `Date`, you can use [`Date.getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) to retrieve the millisecond value.

For the example you have shown, if you have a string:

```
String datestr = "2014-14-03 01:39:00";
```

Then the matching `SimpleDateFormat` would be:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss");
```

And conversion would be:

```
long millis = format.parse(datestr).getTime();
```

It's no problem to use `Date` for this, as the constructors and `getTime()` are still some of the few remaining non-deprecated components.

---

*Edit:* I see that you have edited your question to include the use of `Date`. The constructor you are using is deprecated, and is also not very flexible wrt. input (you have to have the date components already parsed to use it). A `SimpleDateFormat` provides a non-deprecated way to convert arbitrary strings to dates.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice article on the Date APIs that can be found here. 
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-time-elapsed-in-days-hours-minutes-seconds/

In order to convert to milliseconds, simply do some basic math.

Comment: The math to convert a date to milliseconds is far from basic (consider leap time, etc. -- also timezone conversions if not in UTC). There's no need to do the math by hand as all available date APIs already provide a facility to convert to millisecond epoch time.